# Flow builder - Style

Tags: visual-workflow, style, text, flow-builder

I am currently working on a **flow**  and I would like to make some style changes.
The tool is pretty cool but seems very hard to customize.

1. Is it possible to customize the style of a flow? if yes How ?
2. Is it possible to to set *text alignment* and *bold* on **display text** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have the ability to adjust the UI of the standard components they give you, but you can always create your own custom Lightning Component with all the functionality / UI style that you want and use it as part of your flow

Comment: ok thank you ! What about the 2nd question ? is it also impossible just top set text in bold?

Comment: From what I've read I don't think it's possible.  Someone else more versed with Flows might have a better answer for you

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting to set all your text in all your "Display Text" components to bold, I'm not aware of a way to do this. But I've used a workaround for styling Display Text so I only have to update the styling in one place to update everywhere it is used. It is more work to set up initially, but in the long run, it makes maintenance much easier if you have a lot of Display Text components in the Flow (like our caller script flows).

I created a Text Template resource without any text, but put styling in the plain text body field. 
[image: Example Text Template used for styling text]

Then I add this before any text in a Display Text component that I want to display with this formatting. I, of course, have to follow up the text with the matching Text Template to close out whatever styling I added. E.g., the first Text Template may be  and the matching Text Template would just be

Add these Text Templates as resources before and after any text you want to style a specific way. Then, if you ever want to change the styling, you only need to update the Text Template resource, rather than every Display Text component. I know it isn't a great workaround, but I got really tired of updating font colors and sizes on dozens of different Display Text components! :)
[image: Example of Text Templates in a Display Text component]

Comment: clever -- nice!