# Styling of flows used in communities

Tags: community, visual-workflow, community-builder, theme-branding

I am trying to understand whether when a theme is applied to a community (see e.g. [Standard Design Tokens for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_tokens.htm)), any flows presented in that community can be made to respect the theme.

This existing post [Flow builder - Style](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256533/flow-builder-style) suggests the answer is "no". But not respecting the styling in use in the community seems like a big failure and perhaps reason enough to go off and build something rather than use flows. (The default flow styling is also very dull - various shades of grey.)

The flow HTML uses the SLDS class names such as `slds-form-element__label`; is there some way to inject the community themes into the CSS file?

Advice/experiences with this appreciated.

Comment: would using a lwc in a flow be an option? Or embedding the flow in a custom aura component? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm?search_text=flow

Comment: Thanks @KrisGoncalves The latter sounds more promising; how could that add the community styling?

Comment: I was brainstorming more than anything as I haven't done this sort of thing. I was thinking aura component in hopes that you could override the CSS or utilize the doc you mentioned (Standard Design Tokens).